# Can i select date that have 00:00:00 and count it using php

Tags: php, mysql

This is my output

[image]

can i select only the date that have 00:00:00 time and count them?

```
"SELECT COUNT(date_format(time_in, '%H:%i:%s' ='00:00:00')) as `time` 
     FROM dtr_compute"
```

Comment: you can also use `like`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your comparison in the WHERE clause, also I think the bracket is in the wrong place for your call to `date_format()` - it was after the value you wanted to compare it with...

```
SELECT COUNT(time_in) as `time` 
    FROM dtr_compute
    WHERE  date_format(time_in, '%H:%i:%s') = '00:00:00'
```